# index of nilpotence

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dots ,\lambda_r$ its engevalues. Now let be $Q(x) = (x - \lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\cdots (x-\lambda_n)$ a polynomial, show that $Q(A)$ is nilpotent. What is the index of nilpotence?

I have studying for an exam of Linear Algebra, now I have to solve this exercise. I know that $\lambda_j$ is an engevalue of $A$ related with $v_j$ $\iff$ $Q(\lambda_j)$ is an engevalue of $Q(A)$ related with $v_j$. Ok, since $Q(\lambda_j)=0$ we have $Q(A)$ is nilpotent, but I can see what is the index of nilpotence.

Can you help me??

Comment: What is the definition of index of nilpotence? I don't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of that matrix is then $(x-\lambda_1)^{p_1}...(x-\lambda_r)^{p_r}$ where the sum of positive integers $p_i$ is $\le n$. If $p$ is the maximal of $p_i$
then $Q(A)^p=0$ and the index of nilpotency is $p$.